# How to include a dynamic library in a makefile build

Tags: include, makefile, dll

I am writing a program in Mac OSX 10.6 environment. In my make file, I would like to include a dynamic library /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib as part of my build

I am not familiar with make file syntax from what I have read over the internet, I believe I have to add

-lx /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib

please advise me on whether or not this is correct, or the correct way of including the dynamic library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it

-lsqlite3